# How to add a constraint on module installation in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I have developed a new installable module for Joomla 2.5. But I am stuck on place that is "Client wants that if one specified Component was not already installed then there should be a error message throw while installing our developed module". So is it possible to add such kind of limitation in joomla while installing module.

Answer (score 1):

With most Joomla extension you can create an install `script.php` file which defines an object class that can have various methods for the Joomla installer to execute.

These include:

- `install($parent)`
- `uninstall($parent)`
- `update($parent)`
- `preflight($type, $parent)`
- `postflight($type, $parent)`

As you can see for your specific need you will want to implement your check in the `preflight($type, $parent)` method.

You can read more about it on the [Joomla Doc's website](http://docs.joomla.org/), the [Create a Simple Module tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aCreating_a_simple_module) has a section on "[Adding an install-uninstall-update script file](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aCreating_a_simple_module/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file)"